# Is nslProcess supported for addons in Firefox on OSX?

Tags: javascript, macos, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to write an addon that uses nslProcess to run some osascript commands behind the scenes, based on widget clicks. I found the following addon level code on here, but have not been able to get it to work.

```
player.port.on("star1", function() {

//var args = ['-e','tell application "iTunes"','-e','"stop"','-e','"end tell"' ];

var cmd = '/usr/bin/say';
var args = ['value', 'test'];

var execFile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);

execFile.initWithPath(cmd);

    if (execFile.exists()) {
        process.init(execFile);
        process.run(true, args, args.length);
    }


});
```

I'm using Firefox 25. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can access all of XPCOM via the [`chrome` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html).

Here is a complete example (`main.js`)

```
const {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");

var cmd = '/usr/bin/say';
var args = ['value', 'test'];

var execFile = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile);
var process = Cc["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess);

execFile.initWithPath(cmd);

if (execFile.exists()) {
    process.init(execFile);
    process.run(true, args, args.length);
}
```

There are some caveats with `nsIProcess`, though:

- You need to always provide the absolute path.
- You cannot execute OSX App bundles directly. Either go through [`open(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) or execute the actual executable within the bundle.
- `nsIProcess` is not exactly snappy. It will block the UI for a bit (`runAsync`) and a lot more with `run`, as it waits for the process to finish. Therefore prefer `runAsync` where possible and use this API sparingly.